# Creating progress bar with text using TK in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm using TK progress bar to monitor download percentage.
Here is the partial code i found.

```
s = Style(alarm)
# add the label to the progressbar style
s.layout("LabeledProgressbar",
         [('LabeledProgressbar.trough',
           {'children': [('LabeledProgressbar.pbar',
                          {'side': 'left', 'sticky': 'ns'}),
                         ("LabeledProgressbar.label",
                          {"sticky": ""})],
           'sticky': 'nswe'})])


progress_var = tk.DoubleVar()
progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(alarm, orient="horizontal",length=300,mode="determinate",variable=progress_var, style="LabeledProgressbar")

s.configure("LabeledProgressbar", text="Idle 0 %      ")


progress_bar.place(y=45, x= 200)

file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
download_thread = threading.Thread(target=tool.load)
tool.fileName = file_path
download_thread.start()

while download_thread.isAlive():
    progress_bar.update()
    progress_var.set(tool.progress)
    text1 = tool.proc + " " + str(tool.progress) + "%" 
    s.configure("LabeledProgressbar", text= tool.proc) ## + " " + str(tool.progress) + "%" )
```

if i remove the s.configure it works (without the label).

Comment: If I add the boilerplate to make this run it runs just fine. So the problem must be outside of this snippet. Show us a [mcve].

Comment: tkinter isn't thread safe. If you're trying to configure a widget from a second thread, that can cause unpredictable behavior.